# googleappscript : Post data from one work book

Tags: google-apps-script

Submit values from userform (selected cells) to another google spreadsheet and then find them (search), modify and post it again. I have a source sheet (userform), I need to get values from the selected cells and ranges, submit the values to the destination sheet (another spreadsheet) using ID.

I have attached a Screenshot explaining with color code where the data should go. https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yrfje.jpg [SCREENSHOT][1]

Also Shared two spreadsheets with actual data (Userform and Datasheet) for your reference https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA/edit?usp=sharing

```
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var data1 = form_sheet.getRange(['c3:c8']).getValues().flat();
  var [num, date, name, id, project,group] = data1;

  var data2 = form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').getValues();

  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0 ) {
    var new_row = [num, date, name, id, project, group, JSON.stringify(data2)];
    data_sheet.appendRow(new_row)
  } else {
    var range = data_sheet.getRange('g' + ++row);
    range.setValue(JSON.stringify(data2));
        
  }
}

function searchRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var num = form_sheet.getRange('b1').getValue();
  
  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0) {
    ss.toast('Nothing was found')
    return;
  }

  row++;
  var data1 = data_sheet.getRange('a' + row + ':g' + row).getValues().flat();
  var data2 = JSON.parse(data1.pop());
  form_sheet.getRange('c3:c8').clearContent().setValues(data1.map(x => [x]));
  form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').clearContent().setValues(data2)
}

// Function to submit the data to DataSheet sheet
function oldsubmitData() {
     
  var myGooglSheet= SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); //declare a variable and set with active google sheet 
 
  var shUserForm= myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("UserForm"); //delcare a variable and set with the User Form worksheet
 
  var datasheet = myGooglSheet.getSheetByName("DataSheet"); ////delcare a variable and set with the DataSheet worksheet

var namedRanges = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getNamedRanges();
if (namedRanges.length > 1) {
Logger.log(namedRanges[0].getName());
}
  //to create the instance of the user-interface environment to use the messagebox features

  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  
  // Display a dialog box with a title, message, and "Yes" and "No" buttons. The user can also
  // close the dialog by clicking the close button in its title bar.
  var response = ui.alert("Submit", 'Do you want to submit the data?',ui.ButtonSet.YES_NO);
 
  // Checking the user response and proceed with clearing the form if user selects Yes
  if (response == ui.Button.NO) 
  {return;//exit from this function
  } 
 
  //Validating the entry. If validation is true then proceed with transferring the data to DataSheet sheet
  // if (validateEntry()==true)
 {
  
    var blankRow=datasheet.getLastRow()+1; //identify the next blank row
 
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 1).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C3").getValue()); //Date
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 2).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C4").getValue()); //UserForm Number
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 3).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C5").getValue()); //Student Name
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 4).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C6").getValue()); //ID
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 5).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C7").getValue()); //Project
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 6).setValue(shUserForm.getRange("C8").getValue()); //Group Name
    //I stuck here, get values from moving row (E,13 to 16)
     //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("TotalPresent").getValue());// TotalPresent
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 8).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("SoundRoomDay").getValue());// SoundRoomDAy
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 9).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("GroupDay").getValue());// GroupDay
    //datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 10).setValue(shUserForm.getNamedRanges("TotalDays").getValue());// TotalDays

   
    // date function to update the current date and time as submittted on
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 12).setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('yyyy-mm-dd h:mm'); //Submitted On
    
    //get the email address of the person running the script and update as Submitted By
    datasheet.getRange(blankRow, 13).setValue(Session.getActiveUser().getEmail()); //Submitted By

     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var num = form_sheet.getRange('c3').getValue();
  var data = form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').getValues();

  var datasheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = datasheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0) return;
  
  var range = datasheet.getRange('g' + ++row);
  range.setValue(JSON.stringify(data));
    ui.alert(' "New Data Saved - StudentID #' + shUserForm.getRange("C5").getValue() +' "');

        
   }
}
```

Comment: Did you try the suggested solutions?

Comment: Thanks for Asking :) A new screenshot is attached, which explains what exactly want to achieve. Also shared two spreadsheets with actual data ( i have given color reference just to relate where the value to go)

Answer (score 1):

Here are two functions, `submitData()` to put data from the form to the data table, and `searchRecord()` to search data in the data table and put it into the form (ranges C3:C8 and B10:E20):

```
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var num = form_sheet.getRange('c3').getValue();
  var data = form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').getValues();

  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0) return;
  
  var range = data_sheet.getRange('g' + ++row);
  range.setValue(JSON.stringify(data));
}

function searchRecord() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var num = form_sheet.getRange('b1').getValue();
  
  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0) {
    ss.toast('Nothing was found')
    return;
  }

  row++;
  var data1 = data_sheet.getRange('a' + row + ':g' + row).getValues().flat();
  var data2 = JSON.parse(data1.pop());
  form_sheet.getRange('c3:c8').clearContent().setValues(data1.map(x => [x]));
  form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').clearContent().setValues(data2)
}
```

But data in column G of the data table is a JSON string. It's not very friendly for direct edit.

Note: When you change a value in the cell "B2" you need to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before you click on the "Search" button. Otherwise, `SpreadsheetApp` will send into script the previous value of the cell "B2".

---

Here is the modified `sumbmitData()` function:

```
function submitData() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var form_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('UserForm');
  
  var data1 = form_sheet.getRange(['c3:c8']).getValues().flat();
  var [num, date, name, id, project,group] = data1;

  var data2 = form_sheet.getRange('b10:e20').getValues();

  var data_sheet = ss.getSheetByName('DataSheet');
  var nums = data_sheet.getRange('a:a').getValues().flat();
  var row = nums.indexOf(num);

  if (row < 0 ) {
    var new_row = [num, date, name, id, project, group, JSON.stringify(data2)];
    data_sheet.appendRow(new_row)
  } else {
    var range = data_sheet.getRange('g' + ++row);
    range.setValue(JSON.stringify(data));
  }
}
```

Now it appends a new row if there is no row with the given form number (column A). The previous variant of the function works more like `editData()`, it changes existed data only.

Comment: Thank you, I tried the code, getting blank value. Search code works. thank you

Comment: Since I'm not quite understand what you want, the submit function in my code works more like as edit. It changes rows only for existing form number. It can be tweaked to append a new row if the data sheet has no given form number.

Comment: I've updated my answer. Let me know if it works.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand this 'how about...' part. Could you just post exactly what you have and what you want to have? Even now your screenshot differs from your sheet. It's almost impossible to guess it out.

Comment: it's working as expected :) further to the enhancement, 
1. I need to get values from selection cells - form_sheet.get Range is C3, C7, C8, D4, D6, D8, E9 ... instead of (C3:C8)
2. Instead of Submitting & Searching to Datasheet (in the same workbook), I need to submit and search the data from another workbook using ID/URL (whichever is fast)

Comment: var data1 = form_sheet.getRange(['**c3:c8**']).getValues().flat();

Comment: `C3:C8` -- 6 values. `C3, C7, C8, D4, D6, D8, E9` -- 7 values. You can get any cells, but where is supposed the new value to go? And `E9` -- is a merged cell (in your spreadsheet), it will always contain none, or the same value as `B9` does, I don't know. Probably it's just a mistake. Etc... It's a mess. Just post actual new screenshots and spreadsheet with actual data (same as on screenshots)

Comment: var datasheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById('ID').getSheetByName("DATASHEET")

Comment: Thanks for Asking :)  A new screenshot is attached, which explains what exactly want to achieve. Also shared two spreadsheets with actual data ( i have given color reference just to relate where the value to go)

Comment: [https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NY_ckzEWxU7DCGro5tTqzpiOi6iG5PAQFxpZg0OKodY/edit?usp=sharing]

[https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1QL0jaNts2YRkZTlxmS0bk7V1fVVHBsJFmxS5C05PEmA/edit?usp=sharing]

Comment: Screenshot [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1D5cXH2Vj9VA_CZtmHU4VEF9o6iBXgvCi/view?usp=sharing]

Answer (score 0):

#### Post Data in one row

```
function postdatainoneline() {
  const ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  const sh = ss.getActiveSheet();
  const vs = sh.getRange('B10:E20').getValues().flat();
  sh.appendRow(vs);
}
```

Comment: Thank you :), using this code, data is posted in the same sheet. I want this data sent to the destination sheet using ID and Form number

Comment: Remember to explain why it works. The goal is to educate, not just hand out code.